# Set drawable image as background on custom view

Tags: android

I'm creating a map application and want to know how I add the map-image as background, so I then will be able to draw text on it. I want to create a Custom View class that extends View, then add the  background and finally override the onDraw-method.

My idea is to use the constructor to add the background image, so that my image is deciding the size of the Custom View. Then I can use the coordinates to draw text at certain positions on the image.

Hank

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use any property of extended view in Constructor of Custom class.
so you can assign background in constructor.

like this way..

```
public class TestView extends View{

    public TestView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.your_drawable); 

        }
      }
```

Comment: Thanks! I've tested that and did som test drawing in the onDraw-method. Then I added my view to the layout-file for the activity, but the emulator is saying: "unfortunately myApp has stopped" What can be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can set background image even to a layout using "background" property.
Set it to color, image

```
android:background="@android:color/white"
```

Read more about the property here:
[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:background](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3abackground)